# Is the client able to change the user object for onauthchanged firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was wondering if the client would be able to change the user object from null to some value (through the console) and gain access to authenticated resources without having to sign in.

I understand that you can use the following code:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        console.log("user signed in")
        console.log(user)
    } else {
        console.log("user has signed out")
    }
});
```

How does firebase counteract the client attempting to change the user object? 
Is there a more secure way of handling this if this is an issue? 
How would I implement it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear what you think the problem is.  Firebase backend services (as well as your own backend services) can verify the user's ID token to make sure that it cannot be a fake value.  It doesn't matter what the user does in your app - the user ID token can't be faked in order to fool the backend service into think the user is anyone other than an actual authenticated account.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `user` object in the code you shared does not give the user access to additional information in the Firebase Realtime Database.

Inside the security rules for your database, information about the user is exposed through the `auth` variable. This variable is populated by Firebase from the ID token of the user that makes a request to the database, and it cannot be spoofed by regular users.

So while the user may change the `user` variable in your client-side code, this does not impact the `auth` variable in your server-side security rules. This is one of the reasons why it's important to secure data access server-side (like in security rules) and not just client-side.